# The following assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed by 71 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 71 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Row Row:file:///Users/ddo/Desktop/projects/yedek/deneme_kaynak/lib/views/screens/category/screens/first_screen.dart:82:40

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#37132 relayoutBoundary=up13 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: offset=Offset(12.0, 20.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=134.6, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(134.6, 36.0)
...  direction: horizontal
...  mainAxisAlignment: center
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Category> childs = widget.snapshot.data.allCategories
        .where((element) => element.parentId == widget.id)
        .toList();
    return Positioned(
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .2,
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              childs.length != 0
                  ? Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      child: MasonryGridView.count(
                        cacheExtent: 4,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 250),
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          //mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                          //crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                          itemCount: childs.length + 1,
                          itemBuilder: (context, int) => int == 0
                              ? Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 3, 3, 1),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                    gradientFrom[3],
                                    gradientTo[3],
                                  ])),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 12),

                                /*
                                > > > > > ROW < < < < <
                                //first_screen.dart:82:40 Row
                                 */

                                child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      /*Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                              child: Image.asset(
                                                "assets/images/welding.png",
                                                width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .width *
                                                    .14,
                                              ),
                                            ),*/

                                      Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5,
                                            child: Text(widget.category,
                                                textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                    fontSize: 15.0)),
                                          ),
                                          /* Text('see_all'.tr(),textScaleFactor: 1,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white70,
                                                  fontSize: 10)),*/
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      /* Icon(
                                        Icons.chevron_right,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )*/
                                    ]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                              : Column(
                                children: [
                                  int == 1 ? SizedBox(height: 75,): SizedBox(),
                                  InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                                  gotoSuborProd(widget.snapshot, int, childs);
                            },
                            child: Card(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 2, 3, 2),
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        border:
                                        Border.all(color: gradientFrom1[int % 5], width: 5)

                                      /*gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                            gradientFrom[int % 5],
                                            gradientTo[int % 5],
                                          ])*/
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 3),
                                      child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            imageGet(Uri.encodeComponent(
                                                childs[int - 1].imageUrl ?? "")),
                                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0)),
                                            Text(childs[int - 1].category,
                                                textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                    fontSize: 14.0)),
                                            /*Text(
                                                childs[int-1].seoTitle.toString(),textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white70,
                                                    fontSize: 12.0)),*/
                                          ]),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                                ],
                              )

                        // ignore: missing_return
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: please share the screenshot, so I can guide you accordingly

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: @AkhlaqShah error resolved. How can I set the width of the first widget (title widget) to fill the screen?

Comment: move your title widget to top in Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Column` with `Expanded` widget, this will solve `BoxConstraints(w=134.6, 0.0<=h<=Infinity`

```dart
child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 20, horizontal: 12),
  child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded( //here
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
```

Comment: Do the same for both Column

Comment: error resolved. How can I set the width of the first widget (title widget) to fill the screen?

Comment: I think you can change the widget structure like `Column[TopTextWidget, Expanded<Gridview>]`

Comment: The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column instead.

Comment: What is the parent widget? Provide size based on constrains

Answer (score 0):

move your title **Widget** to top of the **Column** like shown in screenshot:

[image]

Comment: ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..7: -1